# Tooltip with pure css - Overflow problems

Tags: html, css

How to properly display these tooltips? With the overflow visible the problem is solved, but I can not use it otherwise the other elements come out of the div. How to solve?
HTML:

```
<div id="test">
<a title='Sample tooltip' class='tooltip'>Test</a>
<br/>
<a title='Sample tooltip' class='tooltip'>Test</a>
<br/>
<a title='Sample tooltip' class='tooltip'>Test</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test{
width: 80px;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 150px;
overflow: auto;
}
.tooltip{display:inline;position:relative}
.tooltip:hover{text-decoration:none}
.tooltip:hover:after{
background:#111;
background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
border-radius:5px;
bottom:18px;
color:#fff;
content:attr(title);
display:block;
left:50%;
padding:5px 15px;
position:absolute;
white-space:nowrap;
z-index:98
}
.tooltip:hover:before{
border:solid;
border-color:#111 transparent;
border-width:6px 6px 0 6px;
bottom:12px;
content:"";
display:block;
left:75%;
position:absolute;
z-index:99
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6JeRU/1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have a `height` for your `#test` container div?  If you take that out and set `overflow:visible` it works perfectly:

http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/6JeRU/4/

```
#test{
    width: 80px;
    /* no height */
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know, but overflow:auto in my case is necessary :/

Comment: Hmmm ok I will go back to the drawing board.  Is the fixed height necessary too?

Comment: Yes, I can't use not even min-width :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new clear fix?

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: mmm... how to apply for my case?